# Variable input size U-net in TensorFlow, issues in deconvolution

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, unet-neural-network

I am trying to implement a variable input size U-net in TensorFlow. I realize that this can happen only if the net consists exclusively of convolution operations and I am ok with that.

The problem arises when I am trying to create a skip connection to a previous layer with concatenation.

Having a layer with shape (701,100) and applying a (2,2) maxpooling results into a (350,50) shaped tensor. If then I upsample it by (2,2) I get a (700,100) shaped tensor that cant be concatenated to the original since they have different shapes.

This usually can be resolved by padding or trimming this tensor to the original shape. To do this I need a reference to the shape of the tensor.

But since I want the net to take variable sized inputs I have declared a shape of (None,None,None,3). So when I try to reference to the shape of a layer it returns errors because it tries to perform mathematical operations using None.

**Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.image.pad_to_bounding_box" (type TFOpLambda).
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int**'

---

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.